MPU6886 with Arduino Mega 2560: Steering Angle Calculation and Drift Issue
I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the steering angle of a vehicle using an MPU6886 sensor connected to an Arduino Mega 2560. The issue I'm facing is that the steering angle drifts with each complete rotation. Here's the problem in detail:
After the first rotation (360 degrees), the angle reading is correct.
After the second rotation, the angle reading shows 360 + 4 degrees.
After the third rotation, it shows 360 + 12 degrees, and the zero angle shifts by 12 degrees.
With each subsequent rotation, the drift increases.
Here is the code I'm using:


#include <Wire.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// MPU6886 I2C address
#define MPU6886_ADDR 0x68
#define MPU6886_GYRO_XOUT_H 0x43

// Ethernet setup
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; // Replace with your Ethernet shield MAC address
IPAddress ip(169, 254, 5, 2); // Replace with your desired IP address
EthernetServer server(80);

// Global variables
float totalAngle = 0.0;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
float gyroZ_zero = 0.0;
const float stationaryThreshold = 0.05; // Threshold to detect if the sensor is stationary
unsigned long ethernetInterval = 1000; // Interval in milliseconds to send data over Ethernet
unsigned long previousEthernetTime = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin(); // Initialize I2C communication

  // Initialize MPU6886
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
  Wire.write(0x6B); // Power management register
  Wire.write(0x00); // Wake up MPU6886
  if (Wire.endTransmission() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize MPU6886!");
    while (1);
  } else {
    Serial.println("MPU6886 initialized successfully.");
  }

  // Calibrate the gyro to zero
  calibrateGyro();

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip); // Initialize Ethernet with MAC and IP
  server.begin(); // Start Ethernet server
  Serial.print("Server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  previousTime = millis(); // Initialize time tracking
}

void calibrateGyro() {
  int numReadings = 100;
  long sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numReadings; i++) {
    int16_t gyroZ;
    readGyroData(&gyroZ);
    sum += gyroZ;
    delay(10);
  }

  gyroZ_zero = sum / (float)numReadings;
  Serial.print("Gyro zero point: ");
  Serial.println(gyroZ_zero);

  // Reset the total angle to 0 after calibration
  totalAngle = 0.0;
}

void readGyroData(int16_t *gyroZ) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
  Wire.write(MPU6886_GYRO_XOUT_H);
  if (Wire.endTransmission(false) != 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to request gyro data!");
    return;
  }

  Wire.requestFrom(MPU6886_ADDR, 2); // Request 2 bytes of data
  if (Wire.available() == 2) {
    *gyroZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Combine high byte and low byte
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to read gyro data!");
  }
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  float deltaTime = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000.0;
  previousTime = currentTime;

  int16_t gyroZ;
  readGyroData(&gyroZ);

  // Convert gyroZ to degrees per second using sensor sensitivity (assuming ±250 °/s range)
  float gyroZ_degPerSec = (gyroZ - gyroZ_zero) / 131.0;

  // If the gyroZ rate is below the stationary threshold, set it to zero
  if (abs(gyroZ_degPerSec) < stationaryThreshold) {
    gyroZ_degPerSec = 0.0;
  }

  // Calculate angle change using gyroZ rate and time interval
  float angleChange = gyroZ_degPerSec * deltaTime;

  // Update total angle by adding the angle change
  totalAngle += angleChange;

  // Normalize totalAngle to 0-360 degrees range
  while (totalAngle >= 360.0) {
    totalAngle -= 360.0;
  }
  while (totalAngle < 0.0) {
    totalAngle += 360.0;
  }

  // Print totalAngle to monitor the progression
  Serial.print("Total Angle:");
  Serial.print(totalAngle);
  Serial.print("\tGYRO_Z values:");
  Serial.println(gyroZ);

  // Check if it's time to send data over Ethernet
  if (currentTime - previousEthernetTime >= ethernetInterval) {
    previousEthernetTime = currentTime;

    // Check for Ethernet client
    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
      if (client.connected()) {
        // Send the total angle value with a specific format


        client.print("Encoder 1 Angle: ");
        client.print(totalAngle);
        client.println(" degrees, Steering Angle: Right");

        // Print connection status
        Serial.println("Ethernet connection is live.");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Ethernet connection is not live.");
      }
    }
  }

  delay(10); // Adjust delay as needed (to match sensor read rate or for serial stability)
}

Is there a recommended approach to calculate the steering angle using yaw, pitch, and roll from the MPU6886 sensor data? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.
I expect the angle to reset correctly after each complete rotation, showing 360 degrees after one rotation, 360 degrees after the second rotation, and so on without any drift.

According to their datasheet the magic "131.0" figure that you are using for the gyro calibration is only a "typical" value (no error bars or tolerance given) and that's in a provisional datasheet which is all I could find in a quick internet search. There is a Github link in the datasheet for sample code too. Worthwhile looking for a more recent less provisional datasheet for it if you can find one.
The line in your code which needs changing is:
// Convert gyroZ to degrees per second using sensor sensitivity (assuming ±250 °/s range)
float gyroZ_degPerSec = (gyroZ - gyroZ_zero) / gyroZ_sensitiviy;

Try gyroZ_sensitivity = 132.5 as a starting guess based on your data.
I think you will need to calibrate the sensor by turning it through exactly 360 degrees to determine the true value for each sensor (and for each axis). Then save those new actual calibration numbers so that you won't have to do it every time you switch on. To be fair to them +/-1% error on 360 degrees isn't at all bad really. Many electronics components have a similar working tolerance.
